# angularjs - validation error message

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Can someone explain me the following code, I'm new to angular please help me :

```
{% if validation_error %}
   <div>{{ validation_error }}</div>
{% endif %}
```

On web page :

[image]

Full code :

```
<form name="login" method="POST" action="/app/login">
    <div class="form-container">
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm text-uppercase" id="username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username">
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
        </fieldset>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block">signin</button>
        {% if validation_error %}
            <div class="small text-danger m-t-1">{{ validation_error }}</div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You'll need the js as well to understand it.  It checks if there was a validation error (if the variable in angular `validation_error`) is true, and then shows the div telling you what the validation error was.

Comment: looks like it could be [django angular](http://django-angular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: @marcellothearcane what are the reference js files to use this sort of code

Comment: no idea.  where did you get that code from? it probably has the angular code with it...

Answer (score 0):

Add `ng-show` tag to `div`

```
<div ng-show="login.username.$invalid && !login.username.$pristine" class="small text-danger m-t-1">You name is required.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular validation with form's and inputs' names;

```
<form name="login" method="POST" action="/app/login">
    <div class="form-container">
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm text-uppercase" id="username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username">
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
        </fieldset>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block" ng-disabled="!login.$valid">signin</button>

        <div ng-if="!login.$valid" class="small text-danger m-t-1">form not valid</div>
        <div ng-if="!login.username.$valid" class="small text-danger m-t-1">username not valid</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

For more: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_validation.asp

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but this could be the templating syntax using [twig](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/if.html).

*eg.*

```
{% if online == false %}
    <p>no one is online.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is [twig](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/) template syntax.

**example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Webpage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="navigation">
        {% for item in navigation %}
            <li><a href="{{ item.href }}">{{ item.caption }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>

        <h1>My Webpage</h1>
        {{ a_variable }}
    </body>
</html>
```